# Assigning a callback to a UIView's UIButton from the containing UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Right now I have a UIViewController subclass that is hosting a UIView subclass. This UIView has a UIButton, and I want the touch event to be sent to the UIViewController subclass. Right now I have a getter method in the UIView subclass, so I grab the button and assign it by just using the reference from within the UIViewController subclass.

What's the best approach to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Add the action event to your ViewController

```
- (IBAction)myButtonPressed:sender;
```

Now if you're using IB (you should be) just link it up, or if doing this in code then manually create the event link.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: The button is in the UIView's hierarchy, I don't have a direct reference to it unless I call the getter method on the UIView subclass.

Comment: Use the getter then `[myView.myButton addTaget:`

Comment: I guess my question was about a better approach. Not how to assign a callback to a button. Sorry if that was unclear in the question.

Comment: The best approach is to use a storyboard or nib to build your views.